# Installing splitterkit using pip

Tags: python, pip

I tried installing splitterkit package using pip in python but it gives an error like ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement splitterkit (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for splitterkit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the git page of the project: https://github.com/ninjiangstar/wav-splitter-library (splitterkit),

while pip install splitter would lead to another one

(This is the one in Sky's answer
, but the Project description
 of splitter says:

> Carefully split a large text into smaller parts. Optionally, preserve
>   sentence boundaries.

)

Therefore you should use the first one.

I have to note I do not know either of those.

Answer (score 0):

You can try downloading the compressed file from [here](https://pypi.org/project/splitter/#files)
and then unzip and go to the directory and run

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: I have to unzip it in  C:\users\user\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages and then use that command to install can you check the unzipping address.

Comment: you can unzip in downloads and install by running the command. Hope it helps